# How to allow validation for multiple email addresses using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation, email

I am using javascript to validate my page, I have done the validation for email which should follow the basic rules of email id. But I need the validation to allow multiple email addresses. Can anyone please help in adding this. Thanks in advance.

Here is JS Code:

```js
function function1(){
 var exp = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
 var emailid = document.getElementById('mailid').value;
 if(emailid == '' || emailid == null){
  document.getElementById('error4').innerHTML = "* Enter Email ID";
  document.getElementById('mailid').focus();
  return false;
 }else{
  document.getElementById('error4').innerHTML = "";
 }
 if (!exp.test(emailid)) {
  document.getElementById('error4').innerHTML = "* Invalid Email";
  document.getElementById('mailid').focus();
  return false;
 }
  }
```

Comment: How multiple emails should be separated? by spaces?

Comment: Hi! How these email addresses should be separated - by comma, or semicolon? You could just split it to an array and looping a validation check on each.

Comment: email addresses should be separated by comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split your emailid string into an array and then check the emails one by one

```
var emails = emailid.split(',');
```

You can know more about the split method here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
var emails = emailid.split(",");
emails.forEach(function (email) {
  if(!exp.test(email.trim()) {
    document.getElementById('error4').innerHTML = "* Invalid Email";
    document.getElementById('mailid').focus();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the addresses are separated by comma you could do something like this:
*(untested but you should get the idea)*

```
var theString = "an.address@domain.ext, an.other.address",
    stringProper = theString.replace(/\s/g,''),
    addresses = stringProper.split(','), //creates an array of every email
    allValid = true;

    for (var i = addresses.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (addresses[i] == 'an.other.address') {
            isValid = true;
        } else {
            isValid = false;
        }
        if(!isValid) {
            allValid = false;
            break;
        }
    };

function isEmail (theString) {
    var exp = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return exp.test(theString)
}
```